# How to get the actual StackView size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

I added UIStackView in the .xib file and set constraints (I set only 4 - top, bottom, leading, trailing, I didn't set height constraint. You can see them on the screenshot), next put its outlet to the .swift file, next added stack items programmatically. But when I tried to get stack size, I received wrong values.

[image]

```
for item in items {
    //...
    //create itemView
    //...
    myStack.addArrangedSubview(itemView)
    myStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

let maxYRegardingSuperView = myStack.frame.maxY
```

If I tried to get bounds size `myStack.bounds.height` I also get obviously wrong size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't this directly related to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877177/how-to-change-table-cell-height-collapse-and-expand-according-to-its-content-b ???

Comment: @DonMag yes, it is. I could not do with your example and I tried to use views coordinates. But it also unsuccessfully

Comment: OK - instead of starting a new question, it's a better idea to get your other question resolved. See my added comment on that one.